# Does Cantor's set contain a copy of each finite set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, cantor-set

Let $C$ denote the (usual) Cantor's set in the interval $[0,1]$. If $S=\{x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}$ is a finite set of points in $\mathbb R$, is it true that $aS+b\subset C$ for some $a\neq 0$ and $b\in\mathbb R$? (i.e. $C$ contains a copy of $S$)

For the fat Cantor-type sets the answer is yes (from Steinhaus Theorem), since in this case the fat Cantor-type set has positive Lebesgue measure. Also it is known that there exists Lebesgue measure zero sets that contain a copy of each finite set.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but with how every interval in the cantor set has a hole at least one third of it in size, $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ should already be a counterexample if I'm not mistaken

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer. Please, let me know if you have any questions regarding my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a detailed answer.
Let us start with some definitions.

Let $S$ be a subset of $\Bbb R$ and $p,q \in S$ such that $p<q$. We say that a interval $(c,d)$ is a *gap in $S\cap [p,q]$*  if $(c, d) \subseteq [p,q]$ and $(c,d)\cap S=\emptyset$.

We also define, for any gap $(c,d)$ in $S\cap [a,b]$,  the *relative size* of the gap to be $\frac{d-c}{b-a}$.

Given any finite set $F=\{a_0, .... , a_n\}$ where $a_0 < ... < a_n$, we define
$g(F)= \max \left\{\frac{a_i-a_{i-1}}{a_n-a_0} \;|\; i=1,...,n \right\}$.

Our first result is easy to prove.

> 1. Any gap $(c,d)$ in $F \cap [a_0,a_n]$ will have relative size less or equal to $g(F)$.

**Proof:**

Any open interval $(c,d) \subseteq [a_0,a_n]$ such that $d-c \geqslant g(F) (a_n-a_0)$ contains a point of $F$. So $(c,d)$ is not a gap in $F \cap [a_0,a_n]$.

$\square$

Now, let $a,b \in \Bbb R$ where $a\ne 0$ and let $T_{a,b}$ the function defined by $T_{a,b}(x) = ax+b$, for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

Our second result is also easy to prove.

> 2. $g(T_{a,b}(F))=g(F)$

**Proof:**

For all i=1,...,n, in the case $a>0$ we have $\frac{T_{a,b}(a_i)-T_{a,b}(a_{i-1})}{T_{a,b}(a_n)-T_{a,b}(a_0)}= \frac{a_i-a_{i-1}}{a_n-a_0}$. In the case $a<0$ we have $\frac{T_{a,b}(a_{i-1})-T_{a,b}(a_i)}{T_{a,b}(a_0)-T_{a,b}(a_n)}= \frac{a_i-a_{i-1}}{a_n-a_0}$. So, in both case it follows immediately that $g(T_{a,b}(F))=g(F)$.

$\square$

Our next result is a little more subtle to prove.

> 3. Let $C$ be the (usual) Cantor set. Given any two points $r,s \in C$, $r<s$, there is a a gap $(c,d)$ in $C\cap[r,s]$ whose relative size is greater or equal to $\frac{1}{3}$

**Proof:**

Since $r,s \in C$, we know that they have expressions (finite or infinite) in base 3 not containing de digit 1. So

$r=0.r_1r_2r_3...$ where for all $i$, $r_i$ is the digit 0 or 2.

$s=0.s_1s_2s_3...$ where for all $i$, $s_i$ is the digit 0 or 2.

Since $r \ne s$, let $n$ be the smallest index such that $r_n \ne s_n$. Since $r<s$, we must have $r_n=0$ and $s_n=2$.
It follows that
$0< s-r \leqslant \frac{1}{3^{n-1}}$

Now, note that, defining

$r'= 0.r_1r_2r_3...r_{n-1}011111111111...$ e $s'= 0.s_1s_2s_3...s_{n-1}2000000...$,

we have that $(r',s')$ is a gap in $C\cap [r,s]$. Note that $s'-r'= \frac{1}{3^n}$. So the relative size of the gap is $(r',s')$ in $C\cap [r,s]$ is greater or equal to $\frac{1}{3}$.

$\square$

Note that the result 3 above does not hold for **fat** Cantor sets.

Now the main result (the counter-example):

> Let $F=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. There is no  $a,b \in \Bbb R$ where $a\ne 0$, such that $T_{a,b}(F) \subseteq C$.

**Proof:**

Now, consider $F=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, it is easy to see that $g(F) =1/4$. Suppose there is  $a,b \in \Bbb R$ where $a\ne 0$, such that $T_{a,b}(F) \subseteq C$.
Then, by result 2 above, $g(T_{a,b}(F))=g(F)=1/4$.

Case 1: $a >0$. By result 1, any gap in $T_{a,b}(F) \cap [T_{a,b}(a_0),T_{a,b}(a_n)]$ will have relative size less or equal to $g(T_{a,b}(F))$, that is $1/4$.
But, by result 3, since $T_{a,b}(a_0),T_{a,b}(a_n) \in C$ and $T_{a,b}(a_0)<T_{a,b}(a_n)$, there is a gap $(c,d)$ in $C \cap [T_{a,b}(a_0),T_{a,b}(a_n)]$ whose relative size is greater or equal to $1/3$. Since $T_{a,b}(F) \subseteq C$, $(c,d)$ is also a gap in $T_{a,b}(F) \cap [T_{a,b}(a_0),T_{a,b}(a_n)]$ with the same relative size greater or equal to $1/3$. Contradiction.

Case 2: $a<0$. It is completely analogous to case 1. By result 1, any gap in $T_{a,b}(F) \cap [T_{a,b}(a_n),T_{a,b}(a_0)]$ will have relative size less or equal to $g(T_{a,b}(F))$, that is $1/4$.
But, by result 3, since $T_{a,b}(a_0),T_{a,b}(a_n) \in C$ and $T_{a,b}(a_n)<T_{a,b}(a_0)$, there is a gap $(c,d)$ in $C \cap [T_{a,b}(a_n),T_{a,b}(a_0)]$ whose relative size is greater or equal to $1/3$. Since $T_{a,b}(F) \subseteq C$, $(c,d)$ is also a gap in $T_{a,b}(F) \cap [T_{a,b}(a_n),T_{a,b}(a_0)]$ with the same relative size greater or equal to $1/3$. Contradiction.

So, there is no  $a,b \in \Bbb R$ where $a\ne 0$, such that $T_{a,b}(F) \subseteq C$.

$\square$

**Remark regarding fat Cantor sets:** For the argument to work it is critical to have, in any "segment" of the (usual) Cantor set, gaps whose relative size have a positive lower bound (1/3), so we can start the counter-example by getting a set whose gaps have relative size smaller than such lower bound. For **fat** Cantor set, we don't have such property, so the argument above does not apply to fat Cantor sets.

Comment: With these details looks more convincing to me. Essentially it is the same argument as of peabrainiac. But in your result 3 for the fat Cantor set, if the part 'relative size is greater or equal to $1/3$ is replaced by 'greater or equal to $1/2(2^k+1)$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$, then for sufficiently large $n\in\mathbb N$ couldn't we have $1/2(2^k+1)>1/n$? Here $F=\{1,2,\cdots,n,n+1\}$. Or now $a$ plays a bigger role as peabrainiac pointed out?

Comment: @Arian For **fat** Cantor set the argument does not work because we start with a set $F$, that means $n \in \Bbb N$ is fixed. So after knowing $k$, we can **not** change "for a sufficiently large $n \in \Bbb N$".  

In other word, for the argument to work it is critical that the relative size of the gaps in the (usual) Cantor set have a positive lower bound, so we can start the counter-example get a set whose gaps have relative size smaller than such lower bound. The relative size of the gaps in **fat** Cantor set don't have a positive lower bound. I will this as a remark in the answer.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the relative size of gaps need to have a uniform lower bound. This lacks in the fat Cantor set. Thanks for the detailed argument.

Answer (score 4):

$S=\{0,\frac1n,\frac2n,...,1\}$ for any $n\geq5$ is a counterexample.

To see this, take any set $\{0,1\}\subseteq S\subseteq[0,1]$ and assume there were constants $a,b\in\mathbb R$ as you described. Then $b$ and $b+a$ are in $aS+b$ and thus $C$; due to the symmetries of the Cantor set, we can choose $a$ and $b$ such that $b$ is in the left half of $C$ and $b+a$ is in the right, i.e. the interval $(\frac13,\frac23)\subset\mathbb R\setminus C$ lies between them. Since $aS+b$ is a subset of $C$, this means that $aS+b$ and $(\frac13,\frac23)$ are disjoint, and so are then $S$ and $\frac1a(\frac13,\frac23)-\frac ba\subseteq[0,1]$. In other words, since $a$ must obviously be $\leq1$, this means that $S$ has a hole at least $\frac13$ in length in it; for sets $S$ like the one mentioned above that's not the case, so they can't be linearly mapped to subsets of $C$ as you described.

Comment: I am not very convinced by this argument. Wouldn't your proof apply as well to a fat Cantor set? Or am I missing something out. Also since you restrict $a<1$, how can the scaled+shifted middle third interval be always in $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Arian the part I was maybe a little vague about here is the "due to symmetries" thing. In the Cantor set, if you can map $S$ into a small subset of $C$, you can scale that up by a power of $3$ and shift it such that it's still a subset of $C$, but now also spans the large gap in the middle; the crucial bit here is that the gaps are all relatively the same sizes. In the fat Cantor set that doesn't work, since intuitively speaking the gaps get thinner and thinner as you zoom in.

Comment: also, the $a\leq1$ part is not a restriction from my side, but is strictly necessary for the conditions $0,1\in S$ and $aS+b\subset C\subset[0,1]$ to be fulfilled.

Comment: according to your argument: take fat Cantor set, see e.g. Smith-Volterra-Cantor set, then there exists $k$ such that an interval of length $1/2^{2k+2}$ is disjoint from $aS+b$. As you correctly pointed out $a\leq 1$ then $S$ would contain a gap at least the length of $1/2^{2k+2}$. If we take $n$ sufficiently large then this wouldn't be possible either, or not?

Comment: @Arian if we choose $n$ really large in a fat Cantor set, we can still choose a really small $a$ and it will work out. In the Cantor set it is guaranteed that those gaps in $aS+b$ can't get arbitrarily small because all gaps in the cantor set have the same relative size, but in the fat Cantor set, they'll take up a smaller and smaller proportion of $[b,b+a]$ as you choose a sufficiently small $a$.

Comment: It does not matter how small you choose your $a$. What I am saying is that even in the case of a fat Cantor set if $aS+b$ is in $C$ then there exists some $k\in\mathbb N$ such that an interval of length $1/2^{2k+2}$ is disjoint from $S$. But then by your argument $S$ must contain a gap of length at least $1/2^{2k+2}$, but $n$ (the size of the given finite set) can be taken as large as we wish and so we would have the gap much larger then the distance between consecutive elements in your finite set. So by your argument even for fat Cantor set we would get the same result?!

Comment: The point is that you choose $a$ and $k$ after $n$. You're correct in that for any fixed $a$ there's sets $S$ such that this doesn't work, but there's still a valid $a$ for any possible $S$, just potentially very small.

Comment: Sure, $n$ is before $k$ and $a$, but note that you're taking $n\geq 5$ to get to a contradiction. What I am saying is that if you take from the beginning a sufficiently large $n$ then you can always find a $k\in\mathbb N$ such that $1/2^{2k+2}>1/n$. With your argument we would also get the same conclusion about a fat Cantor set.

Comment: You can't though. The larger you choose $n$, smaller the $a$ and $1/2^{2k+2}$ become. To maybe illustrate a bit more what the difference is, because I think the current discussion isn't leading anywhere; in the Cantor set, $[0,1]$, $[0,\frac13]$, $[0,\frac19]$ etc. all contain a gap of a third of their length. In the Smith-Volterra-Cantor set though, $[0,1]$ contains a gap a fourth of its length in size, $[0,\frac38]$ only a sixth, $[0,\frac5{32}]$ a tenth etc. You can find an interval without gaps of one $n$th of its length in size for any $n$, you just have to choose it sufficiently small.

Comment: Say $S=\{0,1/100,2/100,\cdots,99/100,1\}$, i.e. $n=101$. In Smith-Volterra-Cantor set for every $k\in\mathbb N_0$ there is an interval of length $1/2^{2k+2}$ missing. In the lines of your argument the set $aS+b$ would be disjoint from an interval of such a length for every $k$. We can let $k=0,1,2$, in each case $1/2^{2k+2}>1/100$, hence we would get to the same conclusion (if you want to get a contradiction), but we know this is not the case for the fat Cantor set. It's true you can have $k$ so that $1/101>1/2^{2k+2}$, but this doesn't work in favor of the contradiction you want to reach.

Comment: "In the lines of your argument the set $aS+b$ would be disjoint from an interval of such a length for every $k$."  
No, it would not. The intersection of $[0,\frac38]$ with the fat Cantor set already doesn't contain a gap of a fourth of it's length, so that already fails for $k=0$, and smaller intervals require even bigger $k$. There are intervals of length $L$ on which the fat Cantor set doesn't have any holes of length $L/100$ and so on. The difference to the Cantor set is that there, any interval of length $L$ has a gap of length $L/3$, but in the fat Cantor set that's no longer the case.

Comment: You want to prove by contradiction. Suppose $aS+b\subset C_f$ Smith-Volterra-Cantor set for some $a\neq 0$ and $b\in\mathbb R$. Then you conclude $a,b\leq 1$, which is correct. Since $aS+b\subset C_f$ and $C_f$ misses certain intervals of length $1/2^{2k+2}$ for every $k\in\mathbb N_0$ then $aS+b$ is disjoint from these intervals too. But then for $S$ above with $n=101$, we can pick $k=0$ and $S$ would have a gap of length at least $1/4$ and this would provide a contradiction for $C_f$. But we know for $C_f$ this result cannot be true. I think your argument is not correct.

Comment: Similarly for the usual Cantor set, instead of intervals of length $1/2^{2k+2}$ we would have to deal with the ones of length $1/3^k$. Nothing changes. My point is that if your argument was true for the usual Cantor set, then the same would apply to the fat Cantor set. But we already know this is not the case. From your argument you can only conclude that the chosen $a,b$ cannot be such that $b$ is on the left third and $a+b$ on the right third, and then you go to smaller intervals and so on, but I think you wouldn't reach a conclusion, because middle thirds get indefinitely smaller.

Comment: $C_f$ does contain those gaps of length $2^{2k+2}$ for every $k$, but not necessarily in $a[0,1]+b$, so there don't necessarily have to be such big gaps in $S\subset[0,1]$. In $C$ $a[0,1]+b$ always contains such a gap of length $a/3$ though, and the preimage of that is a gap in $S$ of length $1/3$. What I meant in the answer with choosing $a$ and $b$ such that $b$ and $b+a$ are from different halves of $C$ was an attempt at simplifying that explanation by only talking about the middle third; it works because every "section" of $C$ has such a middle third, as opposed to $C_f$.

Comment: Anyhow, I don't think this discussion is getting us any further. I know for sure the sets $S$ in my answer are a counterexample, but if what I've said so far doesn't convince you, I don't think there's much more I can say that will. Maybe you can find another argument that's more clear to you?

Comment: I think it is not correct argument, but thank you for your contribution. I will leave this open, for more discussion from other people.

Comment: ok, peabrainiac, your argument is correct. Ramiro below has provided a detailed variant of your proof.